# How to match both a htmlentified keyword and non-htmlentified keyword at the same time in a fulltext MySQL search

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, keyword, html-entities

I've been learned to keep my data in MySQL as raw as possible. Here's an example of how I store content in my MySQL database:

```
title (VARCHAR, 255) => Références
content (TEXT) => <p>A paragraph about r&eacute;f&eacute;rences...</p>
```

When I output it to a page, I use `htmlentities()` on `title`, but ofcourse not on content. I feel this is the correct way of storing it, since `title` stores only text and `content` stores HTML.

However, I now see a limitation to this: when I'm do a fulltext search to match a specific keyword (such as réferences), I need to search both for `références` AND `r&eacute;f&eacute;rences` in order to retrieve all results.

And now I'm thinking... What is the correct way to solve this problem?

- Review the database and store everything with htmlentities? (Don't want!)
- Do two searches, one for the keyword without htmlentities and one for the one with? (Doesn't seem optimal to me...)

Just for the record, here's my enormous MySQL query, that searches in `page`, `page_content`, `article`, `download`, `member` and `event`, so you have a bit of a picture of what I'm dealing with.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

```
$keyword = utf8_decode(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']));

SELECT 
    *, 
    sum(score) AS total_score
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            "page" as db_table,
            lid,
            sid as page_sid,
            sid,
            hook,
            title,
            meta_keywords,
            meta_description,
            NULL as content,
            NULL as location,
            NULL as company,
            MATCH(title, meta_keywords, meta_description) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM page
        WHERE MATCH(title, meta_keywords, meta_description) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    UNION
        SELECT 
            "page_content" as db_table,
            p.lid as lid,
            pc.page_sid as page_sid,
            NULL as sid,
            NULL as hook,
            p.title as title,
            NULL as meta_keywords,
            NULL as meta_description,
            pc.content as content, 
            NULL as location,
            NULL as company,
            MATCH(content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM page_content pc, page p
        WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        AND p.sid = pc.page_sid     
    UNION
        SELECT 
            "article" as db_table,
            lid,
            NULL as page_sid,
            sid,
            NULL as hook,
            title,
            meta_keywords,
            meta_description,
            content,
            NULL as location,
            NULL as company,
            MATCH(meta_keywords, meta_description, title, content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM article 
        WHERE MATCH(meta_keywords, meta_description, title, content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)   
    UNION
        SELECT 
            "download" as db_table,
            lid,
            NULL as page_sid,
            NULL as sid,
            NULL as hook,
            title,
            NULL as meta_keywords,
            NULL as meta_description,
            content,
            NULL as location,
            NULL as company,
            MATCH(title, content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM download
        WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    UNION
        SELECT
            "event" as db_table,
            lid,
            NULL as page_sid,
            NULL as sid,
            NULL as hook, 
            title,
            NULL as meta_keywords,
            NULL as meta_description,
            content,
            location,
            NULL as company,
            MATCH(title, content, location) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM event
        WHERE MATCH(title, content, location) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
    UNION
        SELECT
            "member" as db_table, 
            NULL as lid,
            NULL as page_sid,
            NULL as sid,
            NULL as hook, 
            NULL as title,
            NULL as meta_keywords,
            NULL as meta_description,
            NULL as content,
            NULL as location,
            company,
            MATCH(company) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM member
        WHERE MATCH(company) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)   
    ) AS sub_query
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY page_sid
ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave `"référence"` unescaped in `content` as well, as it remains correct HTML.

(As long as the HTML header specifies the encoding to be the same as in the database, supposedly UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
```

)

Comment: Thanks. This means I won't use `htmlentities` anymore to output anything on the page? Isn't this a bit more unsafe? And, just out of curiosity: I had this `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` and `AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml .json .rss`in my .htaccess. Also, at the top of my HTML page I had `<meta charset="utf-8">`. What are the differences between these things, if any?

Comment: You'd still use htmlentities when outputting the title. And when generating the `content`: I'd htmlentity it and then back-replace the desired characters ("whitelist-approach": &eacute; -> é).

Comment: For your 2nd question: it is good that Apache knows that it is UTF-8, too. The meaning is equivalent to the above meta-tag (I didn't see your variant of it before...), but for cross-browser compability you cannot state it too often ... Besides, PHP (default_charseT), the mysql driver (mysql_set_charset()) as well as MySQL (on database, table and column level) can/should be set to utf-8. By this, you could avoid writing utf8_decode() as it is stored in the same way as it is outputted.

Comment: Thanks for your insights on UTF-8 consistency. As far as my database goes, it's set to UTF-8. My default charset in PHP is set to "no value". I'll probably be able to use .htaccess to change this.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about your remark about htmlentity-ing `content`. Wouldn't that mess up the HTML-tags like `&lt;p&gt;A paragraph...`
Wouldn't htmlspecialchars be useful in this case?

Comment: htmlentitiy: well, it depends on how `content` is soliceted from the user, right? It could be TinyMCE, raw HTML, .... and `a < b` should normally be converted to `a &lt; g`, unless you can presume your users to be fluent in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

With full-text searches [`IN BOOLEAN MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) I believe you can use the `OR` operator in your expression. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for more detail. You can use this to do it in one query.

The before mentioned would amount to something like this in your code:

```
$keyword = utf8_decode(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword'])); 
$keyword = '(' . $keyword . '*) OR (' . htmlentities($keyword) . '*)';
```

*(bit dirty but I think you can clean that up ;)*

I don't know if the `$keyword` variable can contain more than one word in your case. So I added parentheses to clear that up.

On another note: I'm not sure if the boolean full-text search will see something like `r&eacute;f&eacute;rences` as one word. But I guess it's worth a try ;)

Edit: I just found out that a problem with the before mentioned could be solved using double qoutes around your keyword, like so: `"r&eacute;f&eacute;rences"`. That is, if there IS a problem off course ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but this seems to give me much too many false positives. As you indicated probably the fulltext search does not see `r&eacute;f&eacute;rences` as one word...

Comment: Have you tried adding the double qoutes? Like so: `$keyword = '(' . $keyword . '*) OR ("' . htmlentities($keyword) . '"*)';` If there may be multiple words than you could split them up and do the same trick on each off them.

Comment: Well I guess you would have do it the hard way then. That is by using `LIKE`, but I guess that screws up your sorting method. Sorry! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a french developper working on a french site, I also had the same problem and found a way to solve it while still using the powerfull MATCH AGAINST feature that I thought you could find usefull.
You'll excuse possible english faults, I said I'm french ! :-)

The problem I had was the fact that the "htmlentified" word is not recognised as a single word. For example, <<édité>>, once "htmlentified" appears in my database as <<&eacute;dit&eacute;>> and the MATCH AGAINST function consider it as <<'eacute' 'dit' 'eacute'>> (three distinct words).

But as it was said above a "htmlentified" word between quotes (") is considered as an expression in itself and <<"édité">> is considered as <<"&eacute;dit&eacute;">> (one expression).

So the solution appeared that I needed to keep expressions between quotes as they are, and to use regex to put "htmlentified" words between quotes.

So, here's the code I developped to solve the problem until someone fix the bug in MySQL.

```
    //At start, my variable is "htmlentified", so I need to replace <<&quot;>> with real double quotes <<">>
$Search_Text=str_replace("&quot;","\"",$Search_Text);

//I used the "ENT_COMPAT" option for html_entities, so I need to escape the single quotes
$Search_Text=str_replace("'","\\'",$Search_Text);

//I search if there are text between double quotes using "preg_match_all" with "PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE" option to have starting offset for each of them
//Note that at the start of the regex I keep the eventual "+" or "-" or "(" or ")" just before or after quotes
if(preg_match_all('#([-|\+|(]{0,})(\"(.+)\")([)]{0,})#isU',$Search_Text,$Quoted_Blocks,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
{
    //I Initialise an array that will contain each distinct words and quoted expressions from the search text
    $List_Search_Terms=Array();

    //If the offset of the first quoted expression is not 0, it means that there is some words before that I will put in the array
    if($Quoted_Blocks[0][0][1]>0)
    {
        $Starting_Offset=0;
        $Length=$Quoted_Blocks[0][0][1];

        foreach(explode(" ",trim(substr($Search_Text,$Starting_Offset,$Length))) as $Index=>$Valeur)
        {
            array_push($List_Search_Terms,$Valeur);
        }
    }

    //Then I treat all quoted expressions and words between them that I will put in the array
    for($Index_Bloc=0;$Index_Bloc<count($Quoted_Blocks[0]);$Index_Bloc++)
    {
        //I put the quoted expression unmodified in my array
        array_push($List_Search_Terms,$Quoted_Blocks[0][$Index_Bloc][0]);

        //I verify if there's a following quoted expression for I can treat the words in between
        if(isset($Quoted_Blocks[0][$Index_Bloc+1]))
        {
            $Starting_Offset=$Quoted_Blocks[0][$Index_Bloc][1]+strlen($Quoted_Blocks[0][$Index_Bloc][0]);
            $Length=$Quoted_Blocks[0][$Index_Bloc+1][1]-$Starting_Offset;

            //I put the words in between in the array
            foreach(explode(" ",trim(substr($Search_Text,$Starting_Offset,$Length))) as $Index=>$Valeur)
            {
                array_push($List_Search_Terms,$Valeur);
            }
        }
    }

    //After treating all quoted expressions, I put in the array the words that can remain after the last quoted expression
    $Starting_Offset=$Quoted_Blocks[0][count($Quoted_Blocks[0])-1][1]+strlen($Quoted_Blocks[0][count($Quoted_Blocks[0])-1][0]);

    if($Starting_Offset<strlen($Search_Text))
    {
        foreach(explode(" ",trim(substr($Search_Text,$Starting_Offset))) as $Index=>$Valeur)
        {
            array_push($List_Search_Terms,$Valeur);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //If there's no quoted expression in the search, I put all words in the array
    $List_Search_Terms=explode(" ",$Search_Text);
}

//Once I have all words and quoted expressions in the array, I can run through it to put "htmlentified" words (not expressions !) between double quotes
foreach($List_Search_Terms as $Index=>$Value)
{
    //I control that the line of the array doesn't contain double-quotes (which I won't touch) and if there are "&" and ";" characters that means an "htmlentified" word
    if(!preg_match('#"#',$Value) && preg_match('#&(.+)\;#isU',$Value))
    {
        //if both conditions match, I put quotes at the beginning and end
        //Note that as abovre, the regex will keep the eventual "+" or "-" or "(" or ")" just before or after the word
        $List_Search_Terms[$Index]=preg_replace('#^([-|\+|(]{0,})(.+)([)]{0,})$#is',"$1\"$2\"$3",$Value);
    }
}

//After that treatment, the array is converted in one single text that can be included in the mysql AGAINST condition
$Final_Search_Text=implode(" ",$List_Search_Terms);
```

There's probably some optimisations that one can bring to it, but as it is, it does the job !